# Animating Pseudo Class Before Parent

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to animate a pseudo class before the parent class.

For example,

```
.parent {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  &:before {
    content: 'something';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    animation: fadeInOut 2s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

So in my mind, this should fade in and out `something` then `parent` gets loaded.. however, that's not the case... I tried taking out `visibility` but still fails... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have an `animation-delay` with a value of `2s` iin your parent element. That is the exact amount of time your pseudoelement animates. If the parent element has an `opacity` of `0`, its child elements, including pseudoelements will remain "hidden" as well.

Comment: Check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/t7xngwzk/). The `animation-duration` was changed to `6s` in your pseudoelement for illustration purposes.